# Почему валидатор ругается?

Tags: html, вёрстка

Валидатор выдает ошибку "No p element in scope but a p end tag seen". Что я сделал не так?

```
                <p>
                    <h2>Мы — маленькая, но гордая<br> 
                    дизайн-студия из Краснодара. </h2>

                    <span class="about_item">Исповедуем принципы минимализма и чистоты. Ставим 
                    математический расчет
                    превыше креатива. Работаем не покладая рук, как роботы.</span>
                </p>
```

Comment: Потому что тег `<h2>` автоматически закрывает ранее открытый тег `<p>`. Заголовки нельзя вкладывать внутрь абзацев.

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое!